# Is there a way to show / hide another dropdown from a different dropdown using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrapping

I used the toggle technique but I didn't like it.

```
<div class="btn-group col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <label>Patient Type</label>
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="Transaction">
        Choose Type
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li href="#corp-toggle" value="Walk-In" data-toggle="collapse">
            Walk-In
        </li>
        <li href="#corp-toggle" value="Corporate" data-toggle="collapse">
            Corporate
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="corp-toggle" class="collapse col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <label>Please Specify your Company:</label>
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="Transaction">
        Choose Company
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li href="#corp-toggle" value="Walk-In" data-toggle="collapse">
            Walk-In
        </li>
        <li href="#corp-toggle" value="Corporate" data-toggle="collapse">
            Corporate
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: provide more info JQuery/JS code if any. How are you handling it currently? and what is the expected behavior

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? If you're familiar with JavaScript, you can take a look at the bootstrap manual: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I've already resolved it using JS. The initial problem before was if the selection is Walk-In from the drop down list, then the other drop would be hidden. If the selection is Corporate, then the other drop down list would be visible.

the JS code was

```
function show(frm) {
        if (frm.Transaction.value == "Corporate") {
            document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("show").style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{
        document.getElementById("show").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
```

I called the function from the first dropdown form:

```
select class="form-control"  Name="Transaction" onClick="show(this.form)
```

Then called the :

```
id="show" style="visibility:hidden"
```

from the second dropdown form